# Why do I get a different SQL-behaviour on two different machines?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Why does this query

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
         T_Installation.IS_UID 
        ,T_Installation.IS_No_Intern
        ,T_Installation.IS_No_Intern
    FROM T_Installation 
    WHERE IS_IS_UID IS NULL 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
            T_Installation.IS_UID
        ,T_Installation.IS_No_Intern
        ,T_Installation.IS_No_Intern 
    FROM CTE 

    INNER JOIN T_Installation 
        ON T_Installation.IS_IS_UID = CTE.IS_UID 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
-- ORDER BY IS_No_Intern
```

run without exception (on my machine),

while this query

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
         T_Installation.IS_UID 
        ,T_Installation.IS_No_Intern
        ,T_Installation.IS_No_Intern
    FROM T_Installation 
    WHERE IS_IS_UID IS NULL 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

throws

> Error 8156 
>   The column IS_No_Intern was specified multiple times for
>   [whatever].

(on my machine)

On ano**ther sql-server, same server-version**, ***both*** variants throw an error...

Comment: the first query should've thrown the same error

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala: Yea, it should - but it doesn't - on the dev-server ... but it does on the prod server...

Comment: Are you also certain that the underlying data is identical on both servers (assuming the data might be the culprit) ?

Comment: Is that the EXACT query? If you have a case sensitive collation and one is IS_No_Intern and the other is Is_No_Intern it would work fine because those names are different. But on a case insensitive collation they are the same. Just guessing here because what you describe is not possible with the code posted.

Comment: And what kind of result does the one without error returns?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: It's 100% certain the underlying data is NOT identical, because we can't have the underlying original data (confidential). But it's not the data that's bothering me in this case, although that might have an impact. I suspect it's a server-setting, like the case-sensitivity than sean lange mentioned.

Comment: @Nenad Zivkovic: The parent installations with their child installations.

Comment: @Sean Lange: This is the smallest possible query to reproduce the problem. It's not the exact query though - that would be about 1000 lines longer.

Comment: Well that query cannot reproduce the issue unless there are different collations.

Comment: Selecting the ***same*** column twice inside one CTE without aliases, I just can't see that happening - collations or no collations.